# Display block not working as thought...?

Tags: html, css-float

I know this is a common question and I've already tried the searched methods. Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZfZK9/ and here's my problem

Basically, I've got a main div container. It has an image and some text. I need the image on one side, then the text on the other. I tried putting the img in a div, setting it's height to 100%, and floating it right, but as you can see in the jsfiddle once the text goes below the image it doesn't keep the column formation.

I'm not sure why the display: block and height: 100% aren't doing any good on the left column.

Thanks

Edit: I'm assuming height: 100% doesn't work because that gets rendered and then text gets added later. I'm still trying to find an elegant solution though, and general-purpose.

Another problem, is when I set both divs (of the image and of the text) to float: left, it just displays the image then the text under it

Comment: Next time click on the "TidyUp" button before saving the fiddle...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Sorry about it

Comment: The `height: 100%` isn't working because there's no height on `main_content`. For instance: [`height: 780px;`](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfZK9/13/). (Note, I also removed `class="clearfix"` on the left-side `div`, since it doesn't seem to make any sense there.)

Comment: main_content kinda resizes on its own atm and I was hoping for it to find the dynamic/new height. That's good to know, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZfZK9/34/

Just create two div's as columns around both sides, then set both those sides to a specific width, then play around with the padding and margin til you get what you want.

To keep your border around your content, I added a `clearfix` which will help contain the two floated columns....

http://jsfiddle.net/ZfZK9/34/

Had to edit a few things, took a bit to get it right, but now all should be working. Contains two floated divs, with a browser proof clearfix added to the mix. If you wanted the image, or the sidebar to appear as if it continues to the bottom, read about [Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/)

Answer (score 0):

You have some css in the html and some in the css so this is hard to follow. What I believe I see is a common mistake where you must consider when you set something to 100% you have to think, 100% of what? It's always the parent of that element. So what is the parent set to? If nothing, there's your problem.

Just remember that if the parent is also set to 100%, the same question will apply.

EDIT: I see the problem now. I misunderstood. What you want to do then is set the width of the right div, the one with the text. Float that right and it should solve the problem.

Comment: I tried that, but now it's acting as if the 400 started from the very left of the parent container. How can I set it up so that the column/div to the right knows it's start position is the right-edge of the first column?